# Querying sibling XML nodes only inside a parent node

Tags: c#, xml, excel, siblings

This might be a basic question but I am new to querying XML files in C#, so any help will be appreciated..

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<StatementList>
  <Point>
    <Statement>
      <StatementString>S1</StatementString>
      <Children>
         <Point>
          <Statement>
            <StatementString>S2</StatementString>
            <Children></Children>
          </Statement>
          <Statement>
            <StatementString>!S2</StatementString>
            <Children></Children>
          </Statement>
        </Point>
      </Children>
    </Statement>
    <Statement>
      <StatementString>!S1</StatementString>
      <Children>
        <Point>
          <Statement>
            <StatementString>S3</StatementString>
            <Children></Children>
          </Statement>
          <Statement>
            <StatementString>!S3</StatementString>
            <Children></Children>
          </Statement>
        </Point>
      </Children>
    </Statement>
  </Point>
</StatementList>
```

I need to query the XML file such that I only get the sibling `<StatementString>`s from each `<Point>`. Ex.:

**A** S1 !S1

**B** S2 !S2

**C** S3 !S3

I am currently using this code to query the XML file but I can't seem to get only the values that I need for each point.

```
            var statementList = from point in pathsDocument.Descendants("Point")
                        select new
                        {

                        };

            var points = from statement in pathsDocument.Descendants("Point").Descendants("Statement")
                         select new
                         {
                             statementString = statement.Element("StatementString").Value,
```

What should I do to only get the values that I need? thanks in advance.
                             };

Comment: what do you mean with this("What should I do to only get the values that I need?")? What do you want to get?

Comment: I only need to get the values of the sibling StatementStrings for each <Point>, like the example that I wrote above.. Cause currently, when I query the XML, it returns all of the StatementStrings including those inside <Children> even for the first <Point>.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?  It should - I ran it on my machine and it gave the data as you wanted.

Comment: There are two `StatementStrings ` values within the `Point`. One from Point and another one is under the statement of the children. Do you want both? or for children only?

Comment: Gjeltema, when I tried to use the code two errors "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'" and "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments" occured. Why is that?

Comment: lexeRoy, I need both.. but they need to be written separately i.e. the two StatementStrings from the first Point should be written in one row, then the two StatementStrings from the first Point inside the children should be written in another row. And so on..

Comment: That's just the part that formats the string, it's not critical, so you could use the rest of the code and print out what you needed.  But, the reason you're seeing that error is you are using some .Net version less than 4.0.  String.Join that takes an IEnumerable was added in .Net 4.0.  I've gone ahead and edited my answer to make it work for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var points = pathsDocument.Descendants("Point");
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            var statements = point.Elements("Statement").Select(x => x.Element("StatementString").Value );
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", statements.ToArray()));
        }
```

I'm sure there's a better way to group them up so you don't have the foreach to get the StatementString collection, but it's late, I'm braindead and I've got work tomorrow, and this should work.